# Dates according to the number of days

Tags: php, sorting, date

I want to classify the dates according to the number of days to have for example: every 1 of the dates, every two, and so on.

```
<?php

$date1= strtotime('2019-09-01');
$date2= strtotime('2020-06-30'); 

$nbjour=($date2-$date1)/60/60/24;

for($i=0; $i <= $nbjour; $i++) {

    setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
    $day = strftime('%A',$date1);

         if ($day === 'Dimanche' || $day === 'Samedi') {
                  $date = strftime('%A %d %B %G',$date1). ' weekend';
            }
            else{
                  $date = strftime('%A %d %B %G',$date1);
            }
     echo $date;
     $date1+=60*60*24; 
     echo'<br />' ;
 }
```

I want to get this result

```
[01-09-2019
01-10-2019
01-12-2019
...
02-09-2019
02-10-2019
...
03-09-2019]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is unclear.

If you want to change a format of printed dates just change `'%A %d %B %G'` to `'%Y-%m-%d'`

If you want to change the order (sort by day first) maybe try something like this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2019-09-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2020-06-30");

$arrayOfDates = [];

while($date1 <= $date2) {
    $arrayOfDates[] = clone $date1;

    $date1->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}

usort($arrayOfDates, function($a, $b) {
    if( $a->format("j") !== $b->format("j") ) {
        return $a->format("j") - $b->format("j"); 
    }

    if($a < $b) {
        return -1;
    } elseif($a > $b) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

```
foreach($arrayOfDates as $date) {
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br/>";
}
```

And what about this weekend detection?

Comment: About the weekend detection, it was for  sort the weekends. And that's solved.
Thank you. Thank you.